# Cannot get Data Attribute after set Data Attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I get data attribute after changed attribute it's always return 0.00.

HTML Default that I created is:

```
<small data-val="0.00"></small>
```

And I change by this jQuery scripts:

```
$('#cart .cart-footer > .footer.discounts > span > span').remove();
$('#cart .cart-footer > .footer.discounts > small').attr('data-val',data.data.data.discount);
```

It's success set data attribute like

```
<small data-val="360.00"></small>.
```

But after I get data it's return 0.00.

```
console.log( $('#cart .cart-footer > .footer.discounts > small').data('val') );
```

How can I solve this problems?

Comment: which version of jquery you are using?

Comment: There's not enough information here to help you. Please edit your question to provide a more complete example - including where the element's value is set and how it gets changed, and where you read it. What you've shown so far works absolutely fine: https://jsfiddle.net/c0akq1vm/

Comment: use `.attr('data-val')` since you set it using `.attr('data-val, value)`

Comment: please make sure data.data.data.discount it will return 360.00

Comment: @ParthTrivedi I use jQuery version 3.1.1

Comment: @SudharsanS Yes, It return 360 and set correctly. but cannot get

Comment: Is this class `.footer.discounts` correct !!! I dont think so

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('small').attr('data-val', "360.00");

console.log($('small').attr('data-val'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<small>qwe</small>.
```

Use .attr('data-val') since you set it using .attr('data-val, value)

Comment: Thank you sir. Why .data() cannot get? Can you give me more information please.

Comment: setting using `data()` and `attr()` they are stored in different location so getting it needs on how you set it

Comment: This has to be a common thing ppl experience...this question/answer deserves WAY more up votes.